# Resharper bug about var?

Tags: c#, resharper

Suppose this code :

```
var loc = myControl.Location;
myControl.Location = new Point(loc.X + 1, loc.Y - 1);
```

Sometimes, Resharper cannot resolve symbols of object properties. Here "X" and "Y".
Workaround is to change "var" by its explicit type. Here "Point".

Does anyone allready have this issue and know how to solve it ?

Comment: What warning message it says?

Comment: Are we talking about a System.Windows.Forms.Control when writing myControl? Or is it another type?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Jetbrains about it?

Comment: @Udontknow It's a real common problem we (at work 4 developpers on ReSharper 9 and now 9.1) have sometimes (1 time every 2 weeks maybe ?)... And yes, myControl is a standard Label.

Comment: @SonerGönül There is no warning message. Just a error saying "cannot resolve symbols of object blabla" and the properties X and Y (in example above) are red. But program build well.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's we are going to do if we don't have any answer here but sometimes, it's faster on stackoverflow and can help someone else later.

Comment: maybe your cache has not been loaded yet

Comment: have been using resharper for years and currently 9.1: I have never seen the problem. Can you send a concrete sample?

Comment: Does this still occur when you uninstall or disable ReSharper? It sounds to me like a VS quirk rather than a ReSharper one.

Comment: @aevitas It's ReSharper who beg for the problem. Not Visual Studio :) So I can disable ReSharper and it will work well of course =)

Comment: @jeromerg Using Resharper for years too and got that problem recently. Maybe since 1 month.